# How to create the pattern like 55555,4444,333,22,1 using loop structures in R

Tags: r, loops

How to create the pattern like 55555,4444,333,22,1 using loop structures in R?

```
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

My attempt:

```
for(x in 5:1){
  cat(x)
  print(x)
}
```

My output:

```
5[1] 5
4[1] 4
3[1] 3
2[1] 2
1[1] 1
```

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'd take a look at `rep` and also `paste` with the `collapse` option.

Comment: I have updated my attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
n <- 5
for(x in n:1){
  cat(rep(x, x), '\n')
}

#5 5 5 5 5 
#4 4 4 4 
#3 3 3 
#2 2 
#1
```

Another version without a loop :

```
n1 <- n:1
cat(paste0(strrep(n1, n1), collapse = '\n'))
```